# How to combine multiple filters aggregation in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using Elasticsearch 5.3. In the Java client, I want to use filters on multiple fields using `AND` logic into a single bucket. Currently, the filter aggregation only supports single `termQuery`. How do I code multiple `termQuery` in the Java client?

```
AggregationBuilders.filter("specific_session", QueryBuilders.termQuery(FIELD_SESSION_ID, sessionId));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a bool query for that:

```
BoolQueryBuilder filters = QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
   .filter(QueryBuilders.termQuery(FIELD_SESSION_ID, sessionId))
   .filter(QueryBuilders.termQuery(FIELD_XYZ, xyz));

AggregationBuilders.filter("specific_session", filters);
```